# can i load multiple json data from single .json file to snowflake?

Tags: json, windows, cmd, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

[I have two dataset which is in json format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTbzR.png)

how can i load multiple json data from single .json file to snowflake.

please help me with this

[I have tried with single dataset and loaded successfully[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEtAE.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRNeb.png)

Comment: Please don’t link to images, add all relevant information to your question as editable text

Answer (score 0):

You can treat your file as a csv file that has only one column per row, which happens to be a JSON value.

The trickiest part is getting your fileformat correct so that your row delimiters work and it doesn't find any column delimiters in your JSON